# Is there a straightforward way to transfer data from a BLE module to my PC?

Tags: embedded, communication, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to send some sensor readings from a BLE module (RN4871) to my Windows 10 laptop.
I have no problem sending them to my phone and receiving them on a serial Bluetooth terminal.
I also have used classic Bluetooth and MATLAB on my laptop to receive data with no trouble. However, I need to use BLE and my laptop.

I did some searching online, and it seems you have to design a custom software for this purpose. I don't have much skill in this area. I tried looking into BLE in detail and it seems there's a lot of prerequisites that I don't know of.

Is there a straightforward solution to this?

Comment: what are you trying to make from the RN4871

Comment: @Jasen A pic sends some data to RN4871 over UART, and the RN4871 should send the data to a PC.

Comment: you can buy a bluetooth adaptor that plugs into USB

Comment: @Jasen The problem is software, not hardware. My laptop has the hardware for BLE. They can connect, but I can't receive the data using a regular serial terminal emulator.

Comment: ok,  you used PC and Laptop in your question, I did not realise they were the same thing.

Comment: @Jasen You're right. I will fix that.

Comment: have you tried the software listed here? https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/4-essential-tools-for-every-bluetooth-low-energy-developer/

Comment: @Jasen You mean the Bluetooth Sniffer? Not sure how that works. I wouldn't want to spend $50-100 on sth that may not work.

Comment: @Jasen You are trying to solve OPs problem by writing a series of comments with a varying degree of quality. That's what answers are for, because what you're doing here is going to create extra work for OP if your answers are wrong (but cannot be downvoted), and if they are right (cannot be accepted, answer left pending forever).